# Calling a web service from a running app

Tags: web-services, service

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Invoking a web service. Need the missing link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554652/invoking-a-web-service-need-the-missing-link)

I feel like an idiot but I can't figure this out.

It seems it should be extremely easy to do but the answer is elusive. I need to call a specific web service method from a running app by only knowing the endpoint address, the WSDL URL, and the namespace and nothing else. This information will be pulled from a database and its contents can change at any time. Is this possible? I'd love to see an example.

Thanks,

Julie

Comment: I assume you're wanting to make a SOAP call since you have a WSDL file? What language is this in? Most languages have some sort of SOAP library that you could use.

Comment: Thanks @dearlbry this is in Java and yes this is SOAP. I'd like to use jax-ws but it seems that this requires the actual interface file from the author of the web service. Might as well get a jar file of his library then in that case as the web service would be of zero use then.

Comment: Ah - sorry, I'm not going to be of much use to you in Java. Try tagging your post with java and SOAP. Good luck!

Comment: Closing this one as a duplicate of the newer question because there's much more detail on the new one.  For future reference, you should edit your questions instead of posting duplicates.