# Invoking a web service. Need the missing link

Tags: java, web-services, hyperlink

Can someone fill in the missing link in the code below?

First way:

The web service interface file is HappyService.

```
JaxWSProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();

factory.getInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
factory.getInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());

//MISSING LINK. Where does HappyService.class come from? I don't have it
factory.setServiceClass(HappyService.class);

factory.setAddress("http://......../happyService");

//Again how do I get HappyService?
HappyService client = (HappyService) factory.create();
```

Second way:

```
String UrlString = "Your WSDL URL";   
   String nameSpaceUri = "urn:Foo";
   String serviceName = "MyHelloService";
   String portName = "HelloIFPort";

   URL helloWsdlUrl = new URL(UrlString);

   ServiceFactory serviceFactory = ServiceFactory.newInstance();

   Service helloService =
            serviceFactory.createService(helloWsdlUrl, 
            new QName(nameSpaceUri, serviceName));

   //Where did dynamicproxy.HelloIF come from? This code won't compile as that file does not exist anywhere
   dynamicproxy.HelloIF myProxy = 
            (dynamicproxy.HelloIF) 
            helloService.getPort(
            new QName(nameSpaceUri, portName), 
            dynamicproxy.HelloIF.class); 

        System.out.println(myProxy.sayHello("Buzz"));
```

Anyone that has a clue as to where these interface classes come from and how they are generated please let me know. It looks like the only way I can do an web service invocation is by writing the SOAP request by hand and I really don't want to do that as it can get very large and error prone.

Comment: Do you use a Web Service Framework? Based on the first example I think you use CXF. The HappyService class must be a class generated by the wsdl2java task provided by CXF. Don't you have the generated classes package?

Comment: I noticed your other question looks like it's an earlier version of this one. I would encourage you to edit your existing question to add more details instead of opening a new one in the future. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Nope, no access to the generated classes. What I want to do is call someone's public web service across the globe.

Comment: Do you have access to the WSDL of the target Web Service? See my answer below this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools that generate webservices Java classes from WSDL definition files.

You could try [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/), which is the standard Java tool for this task.
An other possibility is [Axis](http://axis.apache.org/axis/), which a level higher.

Answer (score 0):

You need a SOAP library such as [Apache Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/). The library will include tools for generating Java classes from WSDLs. You would use that generated code to make the web service calls.

Comment: So basically there is no way to generate these classes on the fly? I mean I want to deploy an application that can run web services by knowing little more than the WSDL URL. Seems like this would be a very common thing to do.

Comment: You could conceivably generate a new client at runtime using Axis2 and load those new classes into the current JVM to call a web service. I've never tried to do that, or even seen a need to do it, before. You could also try to write a "generic" client that examines a WSDL and creates a one-off call to that service. Basically you'd be doing what the SOAP library's generator does, without writing any client code to disk.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your first sample I think you use the [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) framework.

This framework provides a task named [wsdl2java](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) that allows to generate classes from a WSDL file.

Once your classes are generated you can use them in your code to call the Web Service in an easy way without having to build the SOAP message by hand. It's CXF's job to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps if you refer few basics of web-services in java

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-137004.html

http://metro.java.net/